# Show Survey Responses for a survey in Opportunity entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I need to show survey responses for a particular survey in Opportunity entity.

Basically, I need to see below information for a survey in an entity.

[image]

Can we do something so that the Survey Responses tab can be seen in the navigation as below ?
[image]

Edit : I want to email a survey when an opportunity is closed. Then, I want to tag the survey responses related to that opportunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a survey lookup in opportunity entity
2. Create a quick view form for survey entity with whatever look & feel you want (fields & subgrid of survey responses)
3. Insert the quick view form in opportunity form using the lookup created in step 1
4. Fill the lookup with survey id you want, this will work nicely

Comment: How do I get to see the survey responses I receive for a particular opportunity record?

Comment: @RichaTibrewal this is going broad. You should have 1:1 relationship between survey & oppty ie oppty lookup in survey & vice versa.

Comment: If I have opportunity lookup in survey, then, a survey will be associated with a particular opty record. I want to send survey for any opportunity record. Then, I want to tag the survey response with that opportunity record. I used piped data for the same. But, the lookups in the survey response record is not getting populated.

Comment: @RichaTibrewal I see you have another question for this. You have unaccepted the answer here. Accept it again & close this topic here.